# How to visualize a vtu file in python?

Tags: data-visualization, mesh, python-3.8, fluid-dynamics

I am using `meshio` package to extract the information out of a vtu file that represents the 2d version of flow past a cylinder (Von-Karman vortices) at a Reynolds no. of 220 for one time-step.
I am able to extract the x and y coordinates in a variable called data as follows:

```
In[7]: data    
Out[7]: 
array([[0.02692238, 0.40000474],
       [0.02049045, 0.41      ],
       [0.03102019, 0.41      ],
       ...,
       [0.27846185, 0.15545069],
       [0.04423019, 0.05609254],
       [0.04601913, 0.06239963]])
In [9]: np.shape(data)
Out[9]: (12568, 2)
```

Also, I am able to extract any field variable for instance pressure as follows:

```
In [8]: Pressure
Out[8]: 
array([ 0.04950621,  0.05545308,  0.04723278, ..., -0.05356851,
        0.07954962,  0.08006932])
In [10]: np.shape(Pressure)
Out[10]: (12568,)
```

The simulation had `triangle 6` elements i.e. a quadratic element with 3 regular nodes at vertices and 3 extra nodes in the middle of each edge.
Here is the structure of the nodal connectivity.

```
In [14]: cells['triangle6']
Out[14]: 
array([[    0,     1,     2,  3528,  3527,  3531],
       [    3,     4,     5,  3525,  3239,  3238],
       [    4,     6,     5,  3408,  3237,  3239],
       ...,
       [ 1737,   484,   343,  7316,  4145,  4148],
       [ 3204,  3199,  3202, 12296, 12294, 12566],
       [ 3200,  3199,  3204, 12295, 12296, 12567]], dtype=int64)
In [15]: np.shape(cells['triangle6'])
Out[15]: (6142, 6)
```

How do I plot the simulation using this information?

Comment: If anybody can give me the idea even, I can proceed further easily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am answering my own question after 1 year. So, if the point is just to visualise the `vtu` file inside Python. [PyVista](https://docs.pyvista.org/) is something you need. [Here](https://docs.pyvista.org/examples/index.html), they have an excellent tutorial series on how to visualize `vtu` files.

One can also use [`matplotlib.pyplot.scatter()`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.scatter.html) to quickly plot a scatter with the dependent variables as the colormap intensity.

For example, If I want to plot Pressure in 2D domain.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
sc = plt.scatter(x,y, c = pressure)
plt.colormap(sc)
```

If you want to use `plt.imshow()` for nicer plots, then you need to apply interpolation to convert the data to structured grid.